# Minimum size of brackets using \left and \right

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, brackets, delimiters

I would like to use brackets in math mode which stretch automatically like `\left(` and `\right)`, but have a given minimum size, for example:

[image: Example]

Using something like `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` does not work well because it stretches *all* brackets (including the ones which are already big enough). I would just like to put a limit on the minimum size of the brackets.

How can I achieve this?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

How it works:
\begin{align}
    x &= \left( 2 + y \right)\\
    y &= \left( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \right)
\end{align}

How I would like it to work:
\begin{align}
    x &= \Big( 2 + y \Big)\\
    y &= \left( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \right)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it looks much nicer with the original small size but `\left(\strut2` or replace `strut` by `\rule{0pt}{20pt}` for a specific min height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks much nicer with the original small size but

```
\left(\strut2...
```

will force the bracket to be at least the size forced by `\strut`

or replace `\strut` by `\rule{0pt}{20pt}` for a specific min height

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

How it works:
\begin{align}
    x &= \left( 2 + y \right)\\
    y &= \left( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \right)
\end{align}

How I would like it to work:
\begin{align}
    x &= \Big( 2 + y \Big)\\
    y &= \left( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \right)
\end{align}

with rule:
\begin{align}
    x &= \left( \rule{0pt}{11.5pt}2 + y \right)\\
    y &= \left( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \right)
\end{align}

without left/right
\begin{align}
    x &= (2 + y )\\
    y &= \Bigl( \sum_n \frac{n}{2} \Bigr)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```